# Way to get full param value from an URL

Tags: javascript, url

I am try to get the data from the param in the URL

```
http://localhost:8080?test=1&redirectURL=http://localhost:8082/#/abc?param=1
```

I did

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const redirectURL = urlParams.get('redirectURL'); // result: http://localhost:8082
```

but currently, the URL contain the hash code inside URL so the value return just http://localhost:8082

Is there any way to get full url http://localhost:8082/#/abc?param=1 by getting the param redirectURL

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following is useful for you.

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var paramsTest = url.searchParams.get("test");
var paramsRedirectURL = url.searchParams.get("redirectURL");

console.log(paramsRedirectURL)
console.log(paramsTest)
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/dypWKoM

Comment: the one you commented just get the URI http://localhost:8082, I want to get the full URL include hash http://localhost:8082/#/abc?param=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for you

```
  var afterHash = window.location.hash;
        var beforeHash = window.location.href;
         var fullURL = beforeHash ;
         if(afterHash  != '') // if there is something after hash and hash is exists in url then add the afterHash value in full url
       {
         var fullURL = beforeHash +"#"+ afterHash ;
        }
        
         console.log(fullURL);
```

Comment: window.location.hash just get the one after the hash #/abc?param=1. Is there any way to get full URL, I want to get the value from redirectURL and redirect to that URL

Comment: please wait let me edit the answer for you.

Comment: Please try now maybe this can help you. thanks

Comment: hmm, the redirectURL will not be the same everytime, some time the redirectURL will not include hash, some time it does, so this solution is not ok, I think

Comment: i've made some changes and i think it should work for you. check again

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest issue here is that your `redirectURL` is not encoded. It should be encoded before it ends up in the URL, because otherwise the params and hashes from the nested URL are going to spill into the parent URL.

I obviously don't know if it would make sense for your project, but I think I would use [domurl](https://github.com/Mikhus/domurl).

Maybe you should just use `encodeURIComponent` and possibly `decodeURIComponent` later, but I wanted to point out that domurl handles encoding and decoding automatically. Just as an example:

```
var url = new Url("http://localhost:8080?test=1");
url.query.redirectURL = 'http://localhost:8082/#/abc?param=1';
console.log( url.toString() );
// http://localhost:8080/?test=1&redirectURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8082%2F%23%2Fabc%3Fparam%3D1
```

So again, what the encoded URL does is it prevents params from spilling from the nested URL to the parent URL and enables you to read `redirectURL` as a single string that you can then parse again to see/edit whatever params it has. The other important point is that I'm removing the hashtag with `replace('/#/','/')` in order to read the params from `redirectURL`:

Here's a slimmer [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/vLr3uoxk/) where I'm just extracting the param and leave everything else out.

> You'll definitely want to check dev tools consode log instead of the one stackoverflow offers, to make any sense of the objects.

```js
console.log('');
// I'm encoding the redirectURL here, but in the real world it should be encoded before it's added as a parameter.
var url = new Url("http://localhost:8080?test=1&redirectURL="+ encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:8082/#/abc?param=1"));
console.log('url', url);

// So now that I've separated `url.query.redirectURL`, I can read that URL and its params separately...
var redirectUrl = new Url( url.query.redirectURL.replace('/#/', '/') ); // The hashtag is removed
console.log('redirectUrl:', redirectUrl );
console.log('redirectUrl - (param):', redirectUrl.query.param );
console.log('redirectUrl - path:', redirectUrl.path );

// If you need to use redirectURL without modifications you can just take the url param as is:
console.log( 'redirectUrl - no edits:', url.query.redirectURL );

// If you need to edit the params, you could do that and put just back the hashtag 
redirectUrl.query.param = 'changed the param';
redirectUrl.path = '/#' + redirectUrl.path
console.log('redirectUrl - edited:', redirectUrl.toString() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/domurl@2.3.4/url.min.js"></script>
```